# Error in beforeCreate hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property $store of #<Vue> which has only a getter laravel

Tags: laravel, vuex

i use laravel with vuex ,i succesfully configured all setting in my app but i get this error
getting errors:

```
Error in beforeCreate hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property $store of #<Vue> which has only a getter
```

also

```
app.js:164694 TypeError: Cannot set property $store of #<Vue> which has only a getter
    at Vue.vuexInit (app.js:181831)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (app.js:164660)
    at callHook (app.js:167011)
    at Vue._init (app.js:167789)
    at new Vue (app.js:167869)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:183333)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.0 (app.js:190739)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:84
```

my vuex:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import state from './state'
import actions from './actions'
import mutations from './mutations'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
  modules: {
  },
  strict: debug
})
```

resource/app.js

```
import store from './store/store'
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store,
)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution

```
Cannot set property $store of #<Vue>
```

this error means can't set or already used by another function

i already used vue-stash in my app but i can 't use vuex due to vuestash

so i uninstalled  and removed import module everything in my source

Now started working...